# do while condition vb6

Tags: vb6, while-loop

I have a little vb6 program:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim varTemp As Variant
    Dim string1 As String

    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0

    dialog.Filter = "toate fisierele(*.*) | *.*"
    dialog.Flags = cdlOFNAllowMultiselect Or cdlOFNLongNames Or cdlOFNExplorer

    'open the window to select files
    dialog.ShowOpen

    varTemp = Split(dialog.FileName, vbNullChar)

    Do While (varTemp(x) <> "")

    string1 = varTemp(x)
    x = x + 1

    Loop

    Unload Form1
    End

End Sub
```

I want the Do While to loop until it reaches the end of varTemp. However, when I choose two files from the dialog and "Do While" is hit with x = 3 I get "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".  What condition should the "Do While" loop have to loop until the end of varTemp? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
Do While x <= UBound(varTemp)
```

Since `varTemp` will be an array, this will loop until you hit the last element in the array.

In case the user cancels the selection, and `varTemp` is empty, you may check for an empty string before looping, like this:

```
If varTemp <> vbNullString Then 
    Do While x <= UBound(varTemp)

        string1 = varTemp(x)
        x = x + 1

    Loop
End If
```